# EF 6 Code First merge databases to avoid duplicated tables (One database multiple DbContext)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I’m working on several applications which are using EF 6 Code First to access a SQL Server database.
Each application has its own database and DbContext.
Some of the applications have the same entities (e.g. Users and Groups). Currently those tables are duplicated (e.g. each database has its own User table.)
I thought about “merging” all databases into one big database, which will only have e.g. one User or Group table. The individual applications will still have their current DbContext (so they only have access to the tables they need).

Questions:

- Do you think this is a good idea, or would you do something else?
- I’m using Code First Migrations to generate and update my databases.
  Do I need a DbContext containing all the tables, to be able to use migrations and only create/update the new database using this DbContext, or is there a better way?

Comment: Hard to tell. Depends on expected maintenance / changing database requirements per application / the amount of duplicated data (same users/groups/other?). Dependencies between applications is usually harder to maintain than redundant data.

Comment: Data will be the same or almost the same. The “shared” tables (e.g. Users & Groups) are not expected to change. Other tables are expected to change in the future.
The reasons why I thought of merging the databases are:
- The applications are installed on the servers of my customers, and they don’t like it when I use 5 instead of 1 database. (Even when the databases are for 5 different products)
- My customers or I need to enter, script, generate or whatever the same data for each application.